# Android GridView or GridView Effect using Fragments

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I have a series of fragments each with different views that are updated in real time via numerous callbacks. I would like to display each of the fragment views in a grid view such that the user sees a series of tiles that are being updated in real time, N.B. each tile represents a different fragment and therefore has a different view.

Up to now I have implemented grid views with simple adapters, usually extending `BaseAdapter`, inflating a layout in the `getView` method and notifying the adapter of any changes in the data set using `notifyDataSetChenged`. This is fine for fairly simple grid views, but I'm not sure if it is suitable for what I'm trying to achieve here.

Ideally, I don't want to inflate a view in the adapter's `getView` method, but rather simply return the view for a fragment. The problem is the fragment isn't showing when I'm trying to create the grid view and therefore I can't get a reference to it from the fragment's `getView` method. Also the data in the fragments may be updated randomly and fairly regulalry by their callbacks, and so it doesn't seem efficient to continually call `notifyDataSetChanged`. So:

1). Is it possible to implement a grid view using fragments? If so, how?

2). Am I barking up the wrong tree and there is a better way to achieve a grid view effect with fragments? Perhaps a fragment with sub-fragments?

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Barking up the wrong tree. I have now adopted the approach of providing my app with a container `GridLayout` to which I provide the 'tile' fragments at runtime, thereby negating the need to use a `GridView`. The only disadvantage of this method is that I don't take advantage of the performance benefits that `GridView` can have when viewing multiple layouts that have the same view hierarachy, i.e., `GridView` doesn't inflate the view again if it already has one it can use. I was inquiring about `GridView` because I saw that `ViewPager` has a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and so I wondered if the same could be achieved with `GridView`.